# Use Linq to Sum by Index

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection which has 96 values. I would like to sum values for 4 sequential indexes. How can I do this using Linq?

Example

```
collection = {100, 101, 200, 150, 103, 105, 100, 104,  .........., 20, 40, 60, 80};
```

Sum of `(100, 101, 200, 150;)` then sum of `(103, 105, 100, 104;)` ... then sum of `(20, 40, 60, 80;)` This means now my new collection will have 24 values.

How can I do this using Linq?

Comment: Should your data actually be grouped when it's inserted? E.g. `List<Tuple<int, int, int, int>>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can start with this utility function to `Batch` items up based on a given batch size:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        buffer.Add(item);

        if (buffer.Count >= batchSize)
        {
            yield return buffer;
            buffer = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (buffer.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return buffer;
    }
}
```

After that it's as simple as:

```
var query = data.Batch(4)
    .Select(batch => batch.Sum());
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this going to return the first 4 items _every time_?

Comment: @DonBoitnott You're missing something.  Look up "iterator blocks".

Comment: Impressive! Very impressive.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if(buffer.Count > 0)` instead of `if(buffer.Count >= 0)`

Answer (score 4):

You can group by `index/4` to get your sums, like this:

```
var res = collection
    .Select((v,i) => new {v, i})
    .GroupBy(p => p.i / 4)
    .Select(g => g.Sum(p.v));
```

Comment: @Servy I knew I was missing something! It was too cute to be right! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate a group index from the index, group on that, and get the sum from the values in each group:

```
var sums = collection
.Select((n, i) => new { Group = i / 4, Value = n })
.GroupBy(x => x.Group)
.Select(g => g.Sum(y => y.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a new extension method `Partition`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int partitionSize)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var result = new T[partitionSize];
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        result[counter] = item;
        ++counter;
        if(counter >= partitionSize)
        {
            yield return result;
            counter = 0;
            result = new T[partitionSize];
        }
    }

    if(counter != 0)
        yield return result.Take(counter);
}
```

Usage would be:

```
collection.Partition(4).Select(x => x.Sum())
```

This is an alternate way to the `Batch` method posted by [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050464/572644).

Answer (score 1):

First, make a way to group your sets by index. In this case I've chosen to use integer division to make elements 0-3 group 0, 4-7 group 1, etc.

Next, group your elements in to the different sets that will need summing (by the grouping key).

Finally, select the sum of the elements that belong to each group.

```
values.Select((x, i) => new { GroupingKey = i/4, Value = x })
      .GroupBy(x => x.GroupingKey)
      .Select(x => new { Group = x.Key, Sum = x.Sum() });
```

Answer (score 0):

This do that:

```
static IEnumerable<int> BatchSum(int batchSize, IEnumerable<int> collection)
{
    var batch = collection.Take(batchSize).ToList();
    if (batch.Count == 0) yield break;

    yield return batch.Sum();

    var rest = collection.Skip(batchSize);
    foreach (var sum in BatchSum(batchSize, rest)) yield return sum;
}
```

And to use it:

```
var collection = new[] { 100, 101, 200, 150, 103, 105, 100, 104, 20, 40, 60, 80, 11, 13 };

foreach (var sum in BatchSum(4, collection)) Show(sum);
```

And the output would be:

```
551
412
200
24
```

As you see, your collection length has not to be a factor of `batchSize`.

Comment: It's generally best to avoid recursive iterator blocks, where possible.  Traditional methods have a fairly small overhead each time a method is called, but iterator blocks (as well as `async` methods) have a much greater overhead for the "plumbing" that is set up to make the state machine work.  A recursive function such as this is adding a lot of extra overhead creating all of those extra state machines and yielding each of the nested values all the way up to the top.  There's also not any real benefit to using this over an iterative approach.  Oh, and you iterate `collection` multiple times.

Comment: I disagree; recursive iterator blocks are not a bad design flavor. F# for example has even syntax for flattening recursive iterator blocks, which here is achieved by means of a `foreach`. And about over head, obviously one should go with one or another implementation based on her/his priorities; performance? fast development? In this question it is mentioned that there are only 96 items. I am not sure I am suggesting the proper solution but it can be proper if (for example) performance is not a concern here. If performance was the main concern in software development then Ruby would not exist.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian: That still leaves the problem that `collection` is iterated multiple times. In that case, your method shouldn't take an `IEnumerable<T>` but something like `ICollection<T>` or similar.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here. But I do not see a point that the collection is iterated multiple times. A new iterator is created at `var rest = collection.Skip(batchSize);` and again a new one and so on. Where the collection is iterated multiple times? (Or perhaps I am way out of understanding what it is about :)