# How to sum up every array of a List<int[]> or jagged array via index?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, aggregate

I want to convert this part of code to LINQ.
Can anyone help me?

```
var list = new List<int[]>();
list.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 4, 2, 1 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 5 });

var result = new int[4];
foreach (var item in list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        result[i] += item[i];
    }
}
```

Result must be : `{ 11, 15, 8, 10 }` because that is the sum-result

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783931/one-linq-query-that-equals-to-two-inner-loop

Comment: And this is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17050509/4827151

Comment: @Sherlock, I looked up at link, t is very similar and helped me, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this  is the most readable version. No need to `GroupBy`, you can `Sum` every index of every array:

```
int[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(index => list.Sum(arr => arr[index]))
    .ToArray();
```

Since OP is also using a for-loop from 0-3 they all seem to have the same size.

If that's not the case you could use this super safe approach:

```
int maxLength = list.Max(arr => arr.Length);
int[] result = Enumerable.Range(0, maxLength)
    .Select(index => list.Sum(arr => arr.ElementAtOrDefault(index)))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the most readable way if all subarrays has same length

Comment: @tym32167: it seems to be the case, OP is also using a for-loop from 0-3

Comment: @tym32167:added a "super safe" approach ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, what you think about .aggregate() for this task?
what approach would you recommend?

Comment: @gabba: i'd really prefer above approach. Aggregate doesn't make it more readable. Your approach is also just a for-loop hidden in a LINQ query which makes it even less readable

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thank you for clarification. But the question is about how to hide two for loop into linq ;)

Comment: @gabba: no, it's about converting loops into LINQ. If you still use loops inside your query there is no reason in using LINQ since both, performance and readability will suffer.

Answer (score 2):

First thing that pops to my head:

```
var list = new List<int[]>();
list.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 4, 2, 1 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 5 });

var result = list.SelectMany(item => item.Select((innerItem, index) => new { index, innerItem }))
                    .GroupBy(item => item.index, (key, group) => group.Sum(item => item.innerItem))
                    .ToList();
```

*Tim's approach above is cleaner and is better*

Comment: unnecessary groupby for this task, more unnecessary actions and more memory consumptions

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
var list = new List<int[]>();
list.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 4, 2, 1 });
list.Add(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 5 });

var result = list.SelectMany(x => x.Select((z, i) => new {z, i}))
    .GroupBy(x=>x.i).Select(x=>x.Sum(z=>z.z)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Want to do aggregation, so why would not use linq aggregate?

```
        var list = new List<int[]>();
        list.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        list.Add(new int[] { 5, 4, 2, 1 });
        list.Add(new int[] { 5, 9, 3, 5 });

        var addArrayValues = new Func<int[], int[], int[]>(
            (source, destination) =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
                    destination[i] += source[i];

                return destination;
            });

        var aggregateResult = list.Aggregate(new int[4],
            (accumulator, current) => addArrayValues(current, accumulator));
```